# Ubuntu does not detect onboard Ethernet

Tags: networking, 15.04, ethernet

I have just replaced my old broken motherboard with a new one.
I did not format my HD because Ubuntu 15.04 just started as I hoped.

The first time I booted my OS, internet was going great so Ethernet interface was working fine.
After some reboots Ethernet has just died.
I tried to run:

```
ifconfig
```

and the output is:

```
lo        Link encap:Loopback locale
          ...
```

so it can't see any eth0 interface.

I tried to boot from live CD but same result.
Also my motherboard is: [Asrock ZH77 Pro3](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/ZH77%20Pro3/)

What do you think?
Is there anything I can do to solve my problem?

**edit**:
Here is the output of: `sudo lshw | grep product`

```
product: To Be Filled By O.E.M. (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)
       product: ZH77 Pro3
             product: CMX4GX3M2B1600C9
             product: CMX4GX3M2B1600C9
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz
          product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
             product: Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port
                product: Barts XT [Radeon HD 6870]
                product: Barts HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6800 Series]
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
                product: PEX8112 x1 Lane PCI Express-to-PCI Bridge
                   product: CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio]
             product: 82801 PCI Bridge
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
             product: H77 Express Chipset LPC Controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             product: WDC WD7500AALX-0
             product: ST500DM005 HD502
             product: iHAS424   A
```

Comment: You need to identify the chipset for Ethernet. *You are probably missing the driver for a newer Intel Gigabit Ethernet chipset.* Check output from: **`sudo lshw`**

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer,  there is no `eth ` string in the output of that command.

Comment: You need to reviw the output, for details on Ethernet chipset. Or, just use **`sudo lshw -class network`**

Comment: @david6, No output from last command

Comment: Try **`sudo lshw | grep Ethernet`**, or just look at full output from **`sudo lshw`** for brand/model for Ethernet chipset.

Comment: Are there any settings for LAN or ethernet in the motherboard's BIOS? Is there anything disabled?

Comment: @chili555, I have already checked in BIOS and LAN is enabled.

Comment: @david6, I can't find anything in the oputput of that command.

Comment: Can you paste output from: **`sudo lshw | grep product:`**